# Is there a Websphere portlet that allows sso/credential passing in an IFRAME?

Tags: iframe, websphere, single-sign-on, portlet, websphere-portal

The answer to this question is to use the Web Page portlet; however, the way that portlet works does not provide the solution I need. Please read on before suggesting that particular portlet.

The short version is we are transitioning our intranet to a Websphere Portal 7 solution. This means we have several applications on various servers that we'd like to surface in portal. The Web Page portlet does this, but not in a way that meets our needs due to the 2 limitations:

1) Application URLs for the Web Page portlet must be in the same domain. The applications will be local to our domain, but will likely be on various servers.
2) The authentication must be done via a HTTP GET method. This is really quite ludicrous as this would put credentials on the URL. Who on earth would ever want that?

The things this portlet does that do meet our needs are:
1) Allows setting of credentials via field name/value pairs
2) Loads an application in an IFrame

So, pretty much, I need a portlet that gets around these limitations, but loads the application in an IFRAME like this portlet does. It's hard for me to believe a portlet isn't already out there for this sort of need, so any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it fits your needs completely, but the Web Application Bridge uses a reverse HTTP proxy to do a get (or put, etc) request on a url and manipulates it via an iframe in Portal.
Here's the page in the solutions catalog: https://greenhouse.lotus.com/plugins/plugincatalog.nsf/assetDetails.xsp?action=editDocument&documentId=9FAAD6D44DC64231852577EB006F4D9D